# Error with pipx install eth-brownie (pipx : The term 'pipx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet)

Tags: python, chainlink, pipx

I am a noob at this but have googled so much and tried what I can but cannot get it right. The error I get is:

pipx : The term 'pipx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pipx install eth-brownie
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Please assist as I am trying to learn via https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=12500s. Please explain it like you would to a 5 year old :P #andnew

Comment: Comment to my answer for any further questions and help :)

Answer (score 1):

`pipx` is a package installer. The `command not found` suggests that it is currently not installed in your system. You have to install it first.

For Windows/Linux (requires pip 19.0 or later):

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipx
```

```
python3 -m pipx ensurepath
```

Note: To install pip, see [pip/installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)

For macOS: `brew install pipx`

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir, however I did install these 2 above however used "python" and not "python3". It still doesn't work.

Comment: You'll have to install python then, please see python.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

hey there I am also see that problem and I solved . firstly you may write
`pip uninstall eth-brownie` in terminal  then
`pip install eth-brownie` and when downloading to the terminal, you will be given a script path indicated in yellow at the top of the article `"Consider adding this directory to the PATH, or if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location"` and copy and add it to the environment variables.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31685931)